# programmatical approach to compare password in flutter globally?

Tags: flutter, dart

HI I'm new and willing to learn flutter,

I want to compare the password field from a different dart file that containing studentMonitorId, what is the right approach. just want to see an example, Appreciate it in advance.

**Password.dart**

```
class _State extends State<MyPass> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    
  ),
  body: new Container(
    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
    child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          autofocus: false,
          obscureText: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            fillColor: Colors.black12,
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Password',
          ),
        )
        /*RaisedButton(
          onPressed: (){
                              <------- I want to put a condition here 
                                       if the studentMonitorId from 
                                       Events.dart match with 
                                       the Inputpassword from textformfield.
          },
          child: null)*/
      ],
    )
  ) ,
    )
  
);
```

}
}

I want to check and compare the value of studentMonitorId from this map, but
it seems
very difficult for me to think the easiest approach in dart.

**Events.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Events> eventsFromMap(String str) => 
List<Events>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Events.fromMap(x)));

String eventsToMap(List<Events> data) => 
json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toMap())));

class Events {
Events({
    this.eventId,
    this.semesterId,
    this.schoolYearId,
    this.studentMonitorId,
    this.eventName,
    this.eventDate,
    this.eventTimeIn,
    this.eventTimeInDuration,
    this.eventTimeOut,
    this.eventTimeOutDuration,
    this.eventLocation,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
});

String eventId;
String semesterId;
String schoolYearId;
String studentMonitorId;
String eventName;
String eventDate;
String eventTimeIn;
String eventTimeInDuration;
String eventTimeOut;
String eventTimeOutDuration;
String eventLocation;
DateTime createdAt;
DateTime updatedAt;

factory Events.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Events(
    eventId: json["event_id"],
    semesterId: json["semester_id"],
    schoolYearId: json["school_year_id"],
    studentMonitorId: json["student_monitor_id"],
    eventName: json["event_name"],
    eventDate: json["event_date"],
    eventTimeIn: json["event_time_in"],
    eventTimeInDuration: json["event_time_in_duration"],
    eventTimeOut: json["event_time_out"],
    eventTimeOutDuration: json["event_time_out_duration"],
    eventLocation: json["event_location"],
    createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
    updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
);

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "event_id": eventId,
    "semester_id": semesterId,
    "school_year_id": schoolYearId,
    "student_monitor_id": studentMonitorId,
    "event_name": eventName,
    "event_date": eventDate,
    "event_time_in": eventTimeIn,
    "event_time_in_duration": eventTimeInDuration,
    "event_time_out": eventTimeOut,
    "event_time_out_duration": eventTimeOutDuration,
    "event_location": eventLocation,
    "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
    "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
};
```

}

**Services.dart**

```
`import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
 import 'Events.dart';
 class Services {

  //
  static const String url = 'https://my-json- 
  server.typicode.com/skrfffe1/deas/events';

  static Future<List<Events>> getEvents() async{
  try {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    if (200 == response.statusCode) {
        final List<Events> events = 
     eventsFromMap(response.body).cast<Events>();
        return events;
    } else {
         return List<Events>();
    }
   } catch (e) {

    return List<Events>();
  }
 }

 }`
```

Comment: Kindly show the code that you have written till now to accomplish the intended task.

Comment: done inserting the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a [controller](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input) to achieve this:

```dart
final myController = TextEditingController(); // at the top of stateful widget

// TODO add onDispose method to get rid of the controller.
TextFormField(
          controller: myController,
          autofocus: ...
onPressed: () {
if (myController.text == event.studentMonitorId)
    print("success"); // you will want to move to another widget probably, instead of this log message
 }
```

I didnt see where you retrieve the specific event but you know what do do with it since you have coded it right?